# Why is catching a RuntimeException not considered a good programming practice?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

Why is catching a `RuntimeException` using `catch(Throwable exc) {}` not considered a good programming practice? What is the right way to handle RuntimeExceptions?

Also, why does `catch(Exception exc) {}` not catch `RuntimeException`? How is this behavior implemented?

Comment: That `catch` does catch `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Because unchecked exceptions usually are exception that you can avoid by performing a simple check with an `if` statement. I.E. `NullPointerException` can be avoided with `if(myObject != null)`. Also, `if` is faster than `try-catch`. Use `try-catch` when you really need it.

Comment: I would disagree that catching a RuntimeException is bad practice. Catching and then _ignoring_ the error... that's bad.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Usually, a `RuntimeException` indicates a programming error (in which case you can't "handle" it, because if you knew to expect it you'd have avoided the error).

Catching any of these general exceptions (including `Throwable`) is a bad idea because it means you're claiming that you understand every situation which can go wrong, and you can continue on despite that. It's sometimes appropriate to catch `Exception` (but not usually `Throwable`) at the top level of the stack, e.g. in a web server - because usually whatever's gone wrong with a *single* request, you normally want to keep the server up and responding to further requests. I don't normally catch `Throwable`, as that includes `Error` subclasses which are normally used to indicate truly catastrophic errors which would usually be best "handled" by terminating the process.

Fundamentally, when there's an error you need to be very cautious about continuing with a particular task - you need to really have a pretty good idea about what the error means, as otherwise you could go ahead with a mistaken assumption about the state of the world, and make things worse. In *most* cases (not all), simply giving up on a request is better than trying to carry on regardless of a mysterious failure. (It does very much depend on context though - you might not care what went wrong when trying to fetch one piece of secondary information, for example.)

As for catching `Exception` not catching `RuntimeException` - that's simply not true. The only odd thing about `RuntimeException` is that it (and subclasses) are unchecked exceptions, whereas `Exception` and all other subclasses of `Exception` are checked.

Comment: ....hi can you please elaborate how checked and unchecked exceptions behave differently ?

Comment: @SumitPalSingh: There's a lot of good information available already. Read the Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: By leaving `Error` instances bubble up, how do we know which component will catch them ? How will this or those component(s) log those errors ? How do we know what happened once the program crashed due to an error ? Some errors can be difficult to reproduce.

Comment: @Stephan: Usually there's *something* at the top level which will log the error before the process terminates... at which point you'll have a stack trace. The exact details depend on the application. (For a console application, it just happens automatically, for example - just logging to stderr.)

Answer (score 6):

It boils down to the different types of exceptions there actually are.

Checked exceptions (that is, exception classes that extend `Exception`) are typically errors you can **recover from**.

Unchecked exceptions (that is, exception classes that explicitly extend `RuntimeException`) are those that indicate an error in either expected behavior or program state.  You wouldn't get a `NullPointerException` if the state of an object wasn't `null` when you dereferenced it, of course.

Blanket-catching **everything**  - either `Exception` or `Throwable`, which is ***far*** worse -  is not a good practice because you're assuming that you can recover from *any* exceptional behavior.  There are some cases in which you shouldn't, or realistically can't (i.e. `OutOfMemoryError` for `catch(Throwable t)`).  Further, catching runtime exceptions indicates a code smell; it means that you're covering up a coding error.

**Be explicit** about what it is you're catching.

Aside:  Yes, `catch Exception` will also catch `RuntimeException`, since `Exception` is a superclass of `RuntimeException`.  Just the same, `Throwable` will catch `Exception` and `Error`, which is why it's worse to write `catch(Throwable t)`.

Comment: "Be explicit about what it is you're catching." Why though? I don't think this is good programming advice. If you are modeling a class and you want it to never propagate an exception up, catching all `Exceptions` is perfectly fine. (I agree catching Throwable is no good).

Comment: By leaving `Error` instances bubble up, how do we know which component will catch them ? How will this or those component(s) log those errors ? How do we know what happened once the program crashed due to an error ? Some errors can be difficult to reproduce.

Comment: @Stephan: You don't have enough memory to catch an `OutOfMemoryError` so who *cares* what tries to catch it??

Answer (score 5):

Throwable is super class of all `Exception` checked and unchecked(`RuntimeException`) and error.

```
java.lang.Object
     java.lang.Throwable
          java.lang.Exception
               java.lang.RuntimeException
          java.lang.Error
```

Ideally catching error is not a good practice.

And as `RuntimeException` extends `Exception` so it catches all `RuntimeExcption`'s.