# Loop through a list of map effectively

Tags: java, list, loops, java-8, java-stream

Basically I have a `List<Map<String, Object>> listOfValue`and I need to check if the object is instance of byte then encode it to String as shown below:

```
private void convertByteToBase64(List<Map<String, Object>> listOfValue) {

Object value = null;


if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(listOfValue)) {

    for (Map<String, Object> map : listOfValue) {

        if (!map.isEmpty()) {

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                value = entry.getValue();

                if (value instanceof byte[]) {

                    entry.setValue(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((byte[]) value));
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

I am using java 8 and it is working as expected but is it the correct way of doing it or any better way in term of performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current implementation seems to be ok, however, checking for emptiness of the list and the nested maps seems to be redundant.

Some performance improvement may be possibly achieved if parallel streams are used to iterate the list/maps.

```java
private void convertByteToBase64(List<Map<String, Object>> listOfValue) {
    Base64.Encoder base64encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    listOfValue.parallelStream()
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().parallelStream())
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() instanceof byte[])
        .forEach(entry -> entry.setValue(
            base64encoder.encodeToString((byte[]) entry.getValue())
        ));
}
```

[`Base64.Encoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html) is thread-safe: *Instances of `Base64.Encoder` class are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads.*.

Comment: null != entry.getValue() && entry.getValue() instanceof byte[], first condition is seem redundant also, entry.getValue() instanceof byte[] is enough

Comment: Right, thanks for noticing, I edited the [redundant null-check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950319/is-null-check-needed-before-calling-instanceof) out

Comment: @AlexRudenko Thnks for your answer, a quick question why is checking for emptiness of the list and the nested maps redundant?

Comment: @user1999453, explained here: [Is calling isEmpty() before iterating redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852518/is-calling-isempty-before-iterating-redundant)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void convertByteToBase64(List<Map<String, Object>> listOfValue) {

    listOfValue.stream().parallel()
            .forEach(map -> map.forEach((key,value)->{
                if(value instanceof byte[]) {
                    map.put(key, Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((byte[])value))  ;
        }
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use parallelStream and filter as below.

```
private void convertByteToBase64(List<Map<String, Object>> listOfValue) {
           listOfValue.parallelStream().forEach(map -> {
            map.entrySet().parallelStream().filter(entry->entry.getValue() instanceof byte[]).forEach(entry -> {
                entry.setValue(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((byte[]) entry.getValue()));
            });
          });`
}
```